# How to style the frame of the a button?

Tags: gui-construction, style, button

For certain `Appearance` options of `Button` you can control the `Background`, but how does one alter the style of the frame in these cases?

```
Button["xxx", Null, Appearance -> #, Background -> RandomColor[], 
   FrameMargins -> 5] & /@ {"Frameless", "DialogBox", "Palette", None}
```

[image]

It seems like the Button's frame must be styleable, probably with `BaseStyle`, but for some reason I can't figure it out.

**Update:**

I need a button with `Appearance->"DialogBox"` and a specific background and frame style. Your suggestion isn't pixel perfect:

```
Magnify[Framed[Button["x", Null, 
   Appearance -> "DialogBox", Background -> Yellow, 
   ImageMargins->0], FrameMargins->None, 
   FrameStyle->Yellow], 8]
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want to use a nine-patch as the `Appearance` (this gives the most variability in appearances) or are you just trying to get a different frame styling? If that's the case I'd just used `Framed[Button[..., ImageMargins->0], FrameMargins->None]` or something along those lines

Comment: @b3m2a1 see update

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you exactly need but you might have better control using Graphics combined with frameless appearance?

```
    Button[Mouseover[Graphics[{Rectangle[]}], 
  Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[], White, Text["Check", {0.5, 0.5}]}]], 
 Print[10!], Background -> White, Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{default, hover, pressed} = Rasterize[Framed[Style["button ... ", 16], 
     Background -> #[[1]], 
     RoundingRadius -> 10, FrameMargins -> 15, 
     FrameStyle ->   Directive[#[[2]], AbsoluteThickness[5]]], 
   Background -> None, ImageResolution -> 200] & /@
  {{Yellow, Orange}, {LightBlue, Blue}, {LightGray, Gray}}
```

[image]

```
Row[{default, hover, pressed}, 
   Spacer[10], Background -> Black, Frame -> True, FrameMargins -> 5]
```

[image]

```
Button["",  
  Appearance -> {"Default" -> default, "Hover" -> hover, "Pressed" -> pressed}]
```

[image]

**Update:** The issue mentioned by Sau in comments re white background in the corners in `CreateDialog` window is probably version/os related. It does not arise in Version 13.1.0 (Windows 10 -64bit).

```
CreateDialog[{TextCell["Click OK to close"], 
  Column[{Button["", Appearance -> {"Default" -> default, "Hover" -> hover, 
       "Pressed" -> pressed}, ImageMargins -> 5], 
       DefaultButton[]}, 
   Alignment -> Center]}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: If I put the button inside a CreateDialog, it shows the white background at the corners. 
``` CreateDialog[Button["", Appearance -> {"Default" -> default, "Hover" -> hover, "Pressed" -> pressed}]]```. Can you tell a workaround for this?

Comment: @Sâu, you can add the option `Background -> None` to `Rasterize`.

Comment: That doesn’t fix it. The white corners still exist after rasterizing with Background set to none.

Comment: @Sau, the issue is probably version/os related (it does not arise in v 11.3.0 (windows 10).  You might want to post this as a separate question with version/os information.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will look into this.